# Showing Configurable Products in Transactional Emails

Tags: magento-1.9, php, configurable-product, transactional-mail

I'm trying to fix an issue that I have, I'm able to display the product image in my transactional email just fine but when it's a configurable one, the thumbnail is broken. Can anyone please help me understand why?

```
foreach ($wa_data['items'] as $key => $value) {
    $vars = get_object_vars ($value);
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($value->getOrder()->getStoreId())->load($value->getProductId());
    $item = array(
      'url' => $_product->getProductUrl(),
      'imgUrl' => Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($_product->getThumbnail()),
      'name' => $value->getName(),
      'sku' => $vars['_data']['sku'],
      'description' => $vars['_data']['description'],
      'number' => $vars ['_data']['product_id'],
      'qty' => intval($vars['_data']['qty_ordered']),
      'price' => $wa_data['symbol'] . ' ' . intval($vars['_data']['base_price']),
      'total' => $wa_data['symbol'] . ' ' . intval($vars['_data']['base_row_total']),
    );
    $wa_data['items'][$key] = $item;
}
```

and the image is

```
<img src="<?php echo $_item['imgUrl'] ?>
```

Thank you kindly

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
foreach ($wa_data['items'] as $key => $value) {
    $vars = get_object_vars ($value);
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($value->getOrder()->getStoreId())->load($value->getProductId());
    $item = array(
      'url'          => $_product->getProductUrl(),
      'imgUrl'       => Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(135,135),
      'name'         => $value->getName(),
      'sku'          => $vars['_data']['sku'],
      'description'  => $vars['_data']['description'],
      'number'       => $vars ['_data']['product_id'],
      'qty'          => intval($vars['_data']['qty_ordered']),
      'price'        => $wa_data['symbol'] . ' ' . intval($vars['_data']['base_price']),
      'total'        => $wa_data['symbol'] . ' ' . intval($vars['_data']['base_row_total']),
    );
    $wa_data['items'][$key] = $item;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work,  
     Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($_product->getThumbnail()) 

or 

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($_product->getThumbnail())

works, the problem I'm having is if it's a configurable product it shows both images instead of just the one image.